# Extract information from web page throughExcel vba

Tags: html, vba

I have the following html code

```
<tr>
    <td class="fontblue" style="height: 17px">
             Primary Industry Code
    </td>
    <td class="fontlightblue" style="height: 17px" colspan="4">
        <span id="ucOrganisationDetail_lblVPrimarySector">
            FMP CB:Miscellaneous Manufacturing
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I would like to extract the text **FMP-CB Miscellaneous Manufacturing** using `getelementbyID` option in vba. can anyone please help me

I tried using the below vba code but nothing is working

```
objIE.Document.getElementByID("ucOrganisationDetail_lblVPrimarySector").Value
```

Comment: `objIE.Document.getElementByID("ucOrganisationDetail_lblVPrimarySector")(0).InnerText` would be fine if the rest is in order. To get faster results and unless you don't have to use IE, use MS XML 6.0 to get the source code of the webpage and then assign that to a `Htmldocument` object for easier manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

`objIE.Document.getElementByID("ucOrganisationDetail_lblVPrimarySector").innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

You want `.innerText` as mentioned in comments I see.

[.innerText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa219845(v=office.11).aspx)

> Sets or returns a String that represents the text between the start
>   and end tags of a specified object without any associated HTML.
>
> expression.innerText
>
> expression    Required. An expression that returns one of the objects
>   in the Applies To list.

You could use

```
objIE.Document.getElementById("ucOrganisationDetail_lblVPrimarySector").innerText
```

or a CSS selector which says the same thing of:

```
 objIE.Document.querySelector("#ucOrganisationDetail_lblVPrimarySector").innerText
```

The element is correctly selected as you can see with:

[image: CSS query]